# Count frequency of values in subgroup pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I am trying to count the number of True and False values in a pandas df like this. However, I'm having trouble first using groupby() to isolate my groups before using count().

Here's a toy example of my df in which A, B, and C are columns:

```
A   B   C
1   a   true
1   a   true
1   b   true
1   b   false
2   c   false
2   c   true
2   c   true
2   d   false
```

Does anyone have help? Here's my desired output:

```
B   true   false
a   2      0
b   1      1
c   1      2
d   0      1
```

I'm new to coding in python, so many thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pivot a dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47152691/how-to-pivot-a-dataframe)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can try `crosstab`

```
pd.crosstab(df.B,df.C)
C  False  True 
B              
a      0      2
b      1      1
c      1      2
d      1      0
```